# How to send elements from a Source/Flow to 2 or more Sinks according to a condition?

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I have a Source like:

```
Source[String, NotUsed] and a Flow[String, Int]
```

And I want to send the elements to 2 different Sinks according to a condition.

Is it better to do it like:

```
source ~> flow
flow.filter(cond) ~> sink1
flow.filter(!cond) ~> sink2
```

Or Use a Broadcaster like:

```
source ~> flow ~> broadcast
broadcast ~> sink1.filter(cond)
broadcast ~> sink2.filter(!cond)
```

???

What I am actually asking is:
What is the best way(faster) to send an element to the appropriate sink according to a condition?

Is there a way to do it like:

```
if(cond)
   flow ~> sink1
else
   flow ~> sink2
```

Without having to pass filter for all elements twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Partition`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.4/akka/stream/scaladsl/Partition.html). The following example partitions a source of integers into two sinks: one for even numbers, the other for odd numbers:

```
val intSource = Source(1 to 100)
val sink1 = Sink.seq[Int]
val sink2 = Sink.seq[Int]

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink1, sink2)((_, _)) {
  implicit builder => (s1, s2) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val partition = builder.add(Partition[Int](2, i => i % 2))

  intSource ~> partition.in
  partition.out(0) ~> s1.in
  partition.out(1) ~> s2.in
  ClosedShape
})
```